# object carousel in django

Tags: django, carousel

i also want it in col-md-6 size with some pleasing slideshow effect.

i could not display image or show item fetched from database.

I was unable to figure out how to dynamically create 1 item so I added 3 variables of each (image1,image2,image3,etc.)
i dont want form than 10 images in my carousel

```html
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                {% for object in obj %}
              <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>{{ object.title }}</h5>
                    <p>{{ object.sub_title }}</p>
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
              </div>
                           
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What is this? What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: can you clarify the question